# using 2.0 interface with 3.0 laptop

Tags: usb

I have a laptop with only three 3.0 usb ports, no 2.0 ports. I am wondering if it is possible to use a 2.0 interface to function? (I have a Lexicon Omega interface.)

Comment: Do a web search for "usb 3.0 backwards compatible".

Answer (score 0):

i've used my scarlet 2i2 usb2 to my usb3 laptop - no problems!

Other thing ull have to check is if the manufacturer supports newer windows distros and provides drivers, or if the old drivers will function well in  newer system than the one your card was developed for.